# Join strings and separate with a comma using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop

Using PHP, I would like to select certain values from an array of objects, join them to form one continuous string separated by commas, and save this to a variable named `$isbn`.

I have an array of objects named `$items`. A `var_dump($items)` produces [this](https://pastebin.com/7T89TEYQ). I need to select the `item_isbn` value.

My desired result is;

```
echo $isbn

// would produce
// '0-7515-3831-0,978-0-141-38206-7,978-1-30534-114-1'
```

Getting rid of the hyphens would be a bonus but I think I can achieve this using `str_replace`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we go:

```
$isbnList = [];
foreach ($arrayObject as $item) {
    if (isset($item->item_isbn)) {
        $isbnList[] = $item->item_isbn;
    }
}

$isbn = implode(",", $isbnList);
```

Check it:

```
echo $isbn;
```

For your information:

- The `foreach` works because it's an array. It doesn't care each of the item inside it.
- Each of the object (`$item`) in the loop is the default object of php (as the dump data you provided). Which is supposed to be called as `$object->property`. This object's property are not sure to always available, so checking whether it's available by php built-in function names `isset()` is essential.
- By knowing `implode()` is built-in function from php to build a string with separator base on an `one side array` (means each of item in this one side array must be a scalar value (int, string)). We build this array to ready for the call.
- The rest is just about syntax to how-to work with array or object... You can easily lookup on php manual page, eg: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Most popular programming languages nowadays provide us built-in function like this `implode()`, just different naming.